# Simple GET validation

Tags: php, forms

I have GET[] input and would like to carry out their validation. The input data is always a number by. Schema. I want to make sure that the pass number and the appropriate amount - not to throw the sql query.

at this moment I am using the procedures

```
$cc = $_GET['cc'];
if ($cc=='') $cc='9012';$find=array("..", "/", "\\");
$replace=array("", "", "");
$cc=str_replace($find, $replace, $cc);

$eic = $_GET['eic']; 
.... ect.

// where f.ex. 9012 is an real existing data (in dbase) to generate sucure sql question
```

GET[] variable data schema

```
$_GET[$cc] - always 4 digits
$_GET[$eic] - always 4 digits
$_GET[$iy] - always 4 digits
$_GET[$ir] - always 1 digit
```

Can you show me a better way to secure my GET?

Comment: **Secure** your GET, or **validate** it? There is a huge difference between validation and security. Your code is validating the data, but it is in no way a security measure. If you want security, you should use a parameterized query.

Comment: Can we merge this two functions? Validate and secure? From my point - validate = secure or, maybe better, secure is a function of right way validation :)).brgs

Comment: That is incorrect. Validation and security are totally separate things. Sure, by validating that what should be an `int` is indeed an `int` you prevent direct SQL injection on that parameter, but it's not a security mechanism. Parameterised queries are the **only** safe way to secure against SQL injections. Manual validation and filtering *will* fail. Even `mysql_real_escape_string()` isn't sufficient.

Comment: thnks, have you a time to show me a right solution?

Comment: The right solution is to use `intval` to validate (in this case), then use either mysqli or PDO to send parameterized queries. A google for "mysqli parameterized query" should tell you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

If the query you're getting is always a digit you can use the intval() function in PHP to make sure its an int.

```
$eic = intval($_GET['eic']);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: I understand that this would complement already used the code. And what about the number of digits?

Comment: Why would you want to validate this? Sending a longer/shorter number should not break things..

Comment: change in the number of digits in a variable crashes Querry. Of course I support an exception error but when default error is not displayed, the user does not know what happens - nothing is displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can force numeric values by using `intval()`.
You can't, however, represent values with a leading 0 like `0123` using this method.

If you don't have values with leading zeros use this:

```
<?php
    $_GET['cc'] = intval($_GET['cc']);
    strlen($_GET['cc']) == 4 ? $_GET['cc'] : $_GET['cc'] = 0; // Replace 0 with default/error value

    // Repeat the steps above for all parameters...
?>
```

Comment: I have much zeros :) -> 2005, 1001, 9012, 0 :))

Comment: All these values would work just fine. `intval()` converts your value to an integer, hence _leading_ zeros would be cropped. Examples: 0123 -> 123, 0654 -> 654, 0345->345. Hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

> change in the number of digits in a variable crashes Query

Well, the whole point of validation is that you "validate" data and don't even bother disturbing your SQL database in case the data has not been validated. Why would you bother executing a query which you know to be invalid?

I don't really agree with using `intval()` for validation. With `intval()`, you're forcefully changing the value inputted by the user, which is not really validation. A better method would be to use `is_int()` instead.

For security? Nothing beats "Prepared Statements"

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php